# How can we find the video about M.C.Escher and his work?

Tags: reference-request

I have just read *M.C.Escher:More Mathematics Than Meets The Eye* by *Sara Robinson* in *SIAM News*, *Vol 35*, *Number 8*, *October 2002*.
In this article, the author wrote "...He (Hendrik Lenstra) owns more than dozen books about the artist(M.C.Escher), two documentary videos...".

What are the videos mentioned in the article ?

I searched on Google for the videos but there are lots of short videos about Escher(not official...). Are there any official videos about Escher and his work? I really want to find them. I like watching scientific videos when I have lunch or dinner, I usually watch physical documentary films from BBC Horizons.

Please suggest for me some videos.

Thank for reading and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I'm guessing it's [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0973779/), but why not [e-mail Lenstra](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/) to be sure?

Comment: look here for some: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0260261/

Comment: [_Chaos: A Mathematical Adventure_](http://www.chaos-math.org/) (2010) and [_Dimensions_](http://www.dimensions-math.org/) (2008) by Jos Leys, Étienne Ghys, Aurélien Alvarez, et al. are excellent, [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en)-licensed (i.e., free) movies about math. _Dimensions_ mentions Escher.

Answer (score 3):

Why is a short video not official? What makes a video official?

[The Fantastic World of M.C. Escher](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0973779/) (1980)

[Methamorphosis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d5blV9RDgM) (1988)

[Life & Works of Mc Escher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1569383065) (1999)

[The Mathematical Art Of M.C. Escher](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kcc56fRtrKU) (2005)
From the BBC-4 Night of Numbers, just 4 minutes long.

There are two videos on the *official* [Website](http://www.mcescher.com/Film/escheratworkuk.htm).